# AutoMapper - Missing type map configuration System.Object

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net5

I have set up AutoMapper in EF Core in `Startup.cs` like so:

```
    services.AddAutoMapper(
        typeof(EventItemEstablishmentProfile), 
        typeof(EventItemProfile),
        typeof(GroceryItemEstablishmentProfile), 
        typeof(GroceryItemProfile),
        typeof(GroceryStoreItemEstablishmentProfile), 
        typeof(GroceryStoreItemProfile),
        typeof(RestaurantItemEstablishmentProfile), 
        typeof(RestaurantItemProfile),
        typeof(MenuItemEstablishmentProfile), 
        typeof(MenuItemProfile));
```

I have these AutoMapper profiles:

```
namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    public class GroceryItemProfile : Profile
    {
        public GroceryItemProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<GroceryItem, GroceryItemDto>();
            CreateMap<GroceryItemDto, GroceryItem>();
        }
    }
}

namespace Vepo.Domain
{
    public class GroceryItemEstablishmentProfile : Profile
    {
        public GroceryItemEstablishmentProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<GroceryItemEstablishment, GroceryItemEstablishmentDto>();
            CreateMap<GroceryItemEstablishmentDto, GroceryItemEstablishment>();
        }
    }
}
```

A `GroceryItemEstablishment` contains a field of type `GroceryItem` called `VeganItem` so we are talking about a nested mapping here.

When it comes time to using it in code like so:

```
public async override Task<TVeganItemEstablishmentDto> Insert(TVeganItemEstablishmentDto entity)
{
    var toReturnVeganItem = entity.VeganItem;
    var toReturnEstablishment = entity.Establishment;
    var x = mapper.Map<TVeganItem>(entity);
```

I get the error:

> AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Missing type map configuration
> or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: Object -> GroceryItem System.Object ->
> Vepo.Domain.GroceryItem

Why does the error say that type `Object` is involved at all?

Debugging the code we can see the type is not Object:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to map `TVeganItemEstablishmentDto` to `TVeganItem`.  I can't tell from the code itself, but I would *guess* that this equates to mapping `GroceryItemEstablishmentDto` to `GroceryItem`.  That mapping doesn't exist in your profiles.  Do you mean to instead map the `entity.VeganItem` property as the input?

Comment: Yes, whoops! Silly mistake. Mapping type and provided entity did not match. As you suggested, `var x = mapper.Map<TVeganItem>(entity.VeganItem);` does work. Thank you.